# Find the 'Bounds' of a list of x,y coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to work out a quick and efficent way to to work this out, but i'm stuggling a little.

I have an object 'Tile' which contains coordinates (x, y). I then get a list of those objects which form a shape. a simple example would be a rectangle. but it could be a more complex shape. These shapes would represent a 'Room'

What i need is to then be able to get a list of all the boundry tile objects which make up the outside edges of the room. I would then use this for creating a wall around the room for example.

I'm sure there is a simple mathmatical way to do this, but i can't for the life of me think of it.

EDIT:

I guess i'm pretty bad at explaining this:

take a look at the new two point hospital vid 
https://youtu.be/--N_eQMtTB0?t=79

You can see they drag out a room (place items blah blah) and then when they are finished it creates walls around that room.

This is what i'm trying to achieve in a 2D game. If you imagine each of the square on the floor in that video is a tile, starting from 0,0 running upto however many tiles there are (each tile is one coordinate)

I'm simply trying to take a list of tiles which belong to a room, and find the outside tiles so i can then automatically spawn the wall in those tiles.

Comment: there are inner walls as well? are the "tiles" already in order or just "points" in space?   If so, take 20 stones, throw them on the floor and think about how to make a continious wall from them - awkward, is it not? Think about how many walls you can make that are fdifferent - and that is without stupid multiwalls that cross through one and the other when you connect the stones. Any chance of changing the creation process to produce linesegments already?

Comment: If you put constraints on the walls you could put up some initial ones and then swap things until f.e. the overall wall distance is minimal and all tiles connect to one line and no tile has more then 2 connections ..... but you might still have walls that go through each other that way. Your title for this question does not reflect the content of your question btw.

Comment: Wait. i guess i didn't explain myself properly. I'll edit quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different and maybe easier solution than my other, would be to simply check every tile, and if another tile does not exist on any other side of it, you know it is on the boundary. This solution would work for any shape.

Pseudo code:

```
MakeList()
{
    foreach tile in tilelist
       if no tile at tile.x + 1
       or no tile at tile.x - 1
       or no tile at tile.y + 1
       or no tile at tile.y - 1
          add tile to Boundarylist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to one solution would be to check each row and column in your tile grid and return the tile with the minimum y and x values. The general steps would be.

1. Get a list of all x coordinates.
2. Add the tiles with the smallest y value at each x coordinate to your Boundarylist.
3. Add the tiles with the largest y value at each x coordinate to your Boundary list (if not already in the list)
4. Get a list of all y coordinates.
5. Repeat step 2 and 3, adding the smallest and largest x coordinate to your Boundary list (if not a duplicate).

Some pseudo code:

```
void MakeList()
{
   foreach tile in tilelist
      if xcoordlist does not contain tile.xcoord
         add xcoord
      if ycoordlist does not contain tile.ycoord
         add ycoord

   foreach xcoord in xcoordlist
      foreach tile in tilelist where tile.xcoord == xcoord
         add tile with max and min y to Boundarylist

   foreach ycoord in ycoordlist
      foreach tile in tilelist where tile.ycoord == ycoord
         add tile with max and min x to Boundarylist
}
```

Comment: forgive me, but wouldn't this fail if the room wasn't rectangular, such as a L shaped room or a room in the shape of a cross?

Comment: no, since it is checking the min and max of every row and column, it will always return the outside most tiles. it would even work for a U or S shape

Comment: Ah sorry I'm stupid and totally misread that. and having now read it again i'm even more stupid for not having though of this myself. I was making it massivly to complex in my head! Thanks

Comment: hmmm on second thought it might not work for a U/S shape. but for any shape that does not cut in on itself it should...